# All distributed queries fail using Citus task tracker executor

Tags: postgresql, citus

I'm attempting to performance-test distributed joins on Citus 5.0. I have a master and two worker nodes, and a few hash distributed tables that behave as expected with the default config. I need to use the task tracker executor to test queries that require repartitioning.

However, After setting `citus.task_executor_type` to `task-tracker`, all queries involving distributed tables fail. For example:

```
postgres=# SET citus.task_executor_type TO "task-tracker";
SET
postgres=# SELECT 1 FROM distrib_mcuser_car LIMIT 1;

ERROR:  failed to execute job 39
DETAIL:  Too many task tracker failures
```

Setting `citus.task_executor_type` in `postgresql.conf` has the same effect.

Is there some other configuration change I'm missing that's necessary to switch the task executor?

EDIT, more info:

- PostGIS is installed on all nodes
- postgres_fdw is installed on the master
- All other configuration is pristine

All of the tables so far were distributed like:

```
SELECT master_create_distributed_table('table_name', 'id', 'hash');
SELECT master_create_worker_shards('table_name', 8, 2);
```

The schema for `distrib_mcuser_car` is fairly large, so here's a more simple example:

```
postgres=# \d+ distrib_test_int
                   Table "public.distrib_test_int"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target | Description
--------+---------+-----------+---------+--------------+-------------
 num    | integer |           | plain   |              |

postgres=# select * from distrib_test_int;
ERROR:  failed to execute job 76
DETAIL:  Too many task tracker failures
```

Comment: Normally, just setting `task_executor_type` to `task-tracker` should be enough. Could you provide some more information? Which partition method did you use? How many shards do you have? What is the schema of `distrib_mcuser_car`? Do you use any other plugins? Did you do any other configuration changes?

Comment: @AhmetErenBaşak I've updated the question with more information. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task-tracker executor assigns tasks (queries on shards) to a background worker running on the worker node, which connects to `localhost` to run the task. If your superuser requires a password when connecting to `localhost`, then the background worker will be unable to connect. This can be resolved by adding a `.pgpass` file on the worker nodes for connecting to `localhost`.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify authentication settings and let workers connect to master without password checks by changing `pg_hba.conf`.

Add following line to master `pg_conf.hba`:

```
host    all             all             [worker 1 ip]/32            trust
host    all             all             [worker 2 ip]/32            trust
```

And following lines to for each worker-1 `pg_hba.conf`:

```
host    all             all             [master ip]/32              trust
host    all             all             [worker 2 ip]/32            trust
```

And following to worker-2 `pg_hba.conf`:

```
host    all             all             [master ip]/32              trust
host    all             all             [worker 1 ip]/32            trust
```

This is only intended for testing, DO NOT USE this for production system without taking necessary security precautions.